# cURL, two sites and form steps

Tags: php, forms, validation, curl

I have two sites, A and B.

Site A code:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['data']) echo "Thank you";
?>

<form action="" method='POST'>
    <input type="text" name='data'>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Site B code:

```
 <?php 
  $url = 'http://site_a.com';   
  $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true ); 

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $data;
```

Site B display form from site a. Everything is ok, but I need to see Thank you page on site B too. Now, I'm redirected to site A. 
How to display every steps from site A (form / validation result / thank you page) on site B? 
So, I need to display it like iFrame. I know that I can use JSONP too, but I can't display source URL in code (I don't want to publish site A URL to prevent Google indexing)

Answer (score 1):

You are redirected back to site A because when you curl the form from site A, the `action` attribute will become the complete address of the form on site A.

If you want to stay on site B you need to:

- Remove the contents of the `action` attribute before you echo the form on site B; That way the form will post to itself (on site B);
- Add a check in the code of site B to see if a post was made and if it was, add the post parameters to your curl call to site A. Then site A will give you back the correct results (Thank You).

It's probably easier to publish the form separately on both sites...

Answer (score 0):

I would use either iframe or ajax request for that. Since you `echo $data` then site A source is embedded to site B and parsed in the browser as one whole site (not a form from site A).

Comment: As I said before, both iFrame and Ajax is not solution for me. I want to use existing fragment of Site A (form) inside Site B. Site A form write some data to local company database. I dont want to publish this IP address in source.

Comment: if the form is submitted to site A, then you will reveal the IP address in the source anyway. If you use relative action in your form, then it will be posted to site B and A is left out but you should then write a handler for that form in site B as well.

Comment: I was hoping that there is any method when I leave action empty, everything will do on site B. So, I understand to hide IP address of site A, only one solution is to prepare form/validation/database writing on site B?